# Deposition of saturated solution and affect of evaporated water

Tags: water, solubility, solutions, concentration

20g of water is evaporated from 200g of saturated solution of KNO3(aq) at 60°C by heating and the solution was cooled to 20°C. How many grams of KNO3 were deposited? The solubility of KNO3 in 100g of water is 32 at 20°C and 109 at 60°C.

I have a doubt on `"20g water is evaporated from 200g KNO3"` statement. I'm assuming that as 20g evaporated that means the initial saturated solution has mass of 220g. This is at 60°C. I also assume the solubility in g/L.

Now, at **60°C** the max amount of solution that can dissolve is **109**. Thus, if we get 220g this leaves $220-109=111g$ of solvent that is not dissolved.

Then, if the saturated solution is cooled down to **20°C**, the solubility will decrease to **32g/L** while the amount of precipitation we have remains the same. This leaves $111-32=79 grams$ of KNO3 precipitated. Therefore, the final amount of KNO3 deposited is `79g`.

Did I treat the amount of water evaporated in a correct way? I'm not sure whether the water is affecting the total concentration or 'overall' volume of the saturated solution.

Comment: You would serve a good service to yourself and readers, if you evaluate everything via symbolic algebraic expressions and equations. This way you would easier learn the principles and as bonus, both you and readers would easier spot eventual mistakes done.

Comment: if 20g is evaporated from 200g, how could be the initial mass 220g ?? I is like saying I have \$200, I give you \$20 and I initially had \$220. Strange, huh?

Comment: I'm new here and I was looking for that, I appreciate your info.
I'm thinking before the solution get evaporated so initial mass is 220g and I feel this is really wrong because I never cover the topic relating to evaporated water in solubility and I couldn't find the source on internet explaining how it can relate to it's solubility.

Comment: Solubility for given T is the constant. No evaporation related operations affect it.

Comment: So what is the 20g evaporated water tells us?

Comment: You cannot be serious. It says 20 g water was evaporated and the mass of the condensed part of the system decreased from 200g to 180g.

Comment: There's no reason for me to joke, I just want to understand more about this. I do not have any physical or digital source regarding this topic and I only utilize internet. However, the topic covered in this area only covers by the definition of concentration, solubility, and type of saturated soln. I couldn't find the answer of my question making me unable to answer my practice question. How can i proceed with 180g? Is my working for the rest correct?

Comment: It seems to me you are struggling with the basic concepts from which you are supposed to design the answer. As the first step, forget evaporation and focus on concepts of solubility constants and terms related to solute content: %content w/w, w(weight=mass)/v(volume), v/v, molarity, density. Search Wikipedia. When you get it, all the evaporation task will be a piece of cake to you.

Comment: I have bombard my self with the basics especially the conversion and how mass, moles, M, V, P, concentration, temperature relate to each other. I asked here after I'm stuck for days letting my brain to be in diffuse mode and learn something else and I came to the point where I cant spend more time to solve this 1 question. Furthermore, I considered the volume and density in this question however, the density is not given. I treat the question as I'm in the test condition and I can't look up on internet about the density and I must use the values that solely given from the question.

Comment: You have all info needed there. The key point is to relate solubility in x/100mL(about 100g) versus content y g in 100 g of solution. y=x*100/(100 +x). As the task, in opposite to your prior question, does not consider volumes, but masses, you need not to consider densities.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to help to understand how to solve tasks, not the solving itself.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your calculations are a little bit wrong because of the poor choice of the total initial mass. It is $200 g$, and not $220~ g$. So here are the right calculations.

As $100 g$ water dissolves $109g$ $\ce{KNO3}$ at $60$°C, producing a total mass of $209g$, you may deduce that $200g$ of your initial solution contains $(200/209)·109g = 104.3 g$ $\ce{KNO3}$ and $(200/209)·100g = 95.7g$ water.

Now you loose $20 g$ water by evaporation. The amount of $\ce{KNO3}$ is still $104.3 g$. Remaining water is $95.7g - 20g = 75.7g$ water. At the final temperature $20$°C, $100g$ water can only dissolve $32g$ $\ce{KNO3}$. As a consequence, $75.7$ g water can dissolve $(75.7/100)·32g = 24.2 g$ $\ce{KNO3}$. The rest is deposited in the flask. It is $104.3 g - 24.2 g = 80.1 g$.

Please note that the mass has a unit, the gram. It is incorrect to say "the solubility of $\ce{KNO3}$ in $100g$ of water is $32$ at $20°$C and $109$ at $60°$C". You should have said that "the solubility of $\ce{KNO3}$ in $100$g of water is $32 g$ at $20$°C and $109$ g at $60$°C

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I literally just solved the question after Poutnik gave me the hint and I was hesitating to confirm my answer.

Comment: For the note, that's original from the question. I was wondering why it did not state any unit as well.

Comment: Please, both OP and responders, always use as the first step a general algebraic solution, for 3 reasons.: 1/better grasp of principles for OP. 2/ better orientation and spotting eventual mistakes. 3/solution reusability and permanent value.  Use eventually [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88) for mathematical/chemical expression/formula formatting. E.g. \$\$\frac{[\ce{SO4^2-}]}{[\ce{HSO4-}]}\$\$ looks like $$\frac{[\ce{SO4^2-}]}{[\ce{HSO4-}]}$$